# Access main table data from within subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have a 'users' and 'courses' table and the two are related by a 'user_courses' table. This allows 1 user to have many courses etc.

My users table contains 1 million users and I would like to:

- select users of a certain age and gender
  AND
- select the count of exact courses they have in common with another given user

The way I have approached this is to select users where gender and age match what I am looking for, this is fairly easy.

Next I perform a LEFT JOIN and using a sub-query I get the count of all users and the number of courses in common with the given user.

The problem is, in the sub-query, I am have to select all users over again and without repeating the gender = 'female' AND birth_year BETWEEN '1991' AND '1993' in the sub-query, it would select all 1 million users.

```
SELECT 
    u . *, matching_courses_count
FROM
    users u
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(course_id) AS matching_courses_count, uc.user_id
    FROM
        users u
    LEFT JOIN user_courses uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
    WHERE
        uc.course_id IN (SELECT 
                course_id
            FROM
                user_courses
            WHERE
                user_id = 1)
            AND uc.user_id != 1
    GROUP BY uc.user_id) matching_courses ON u.id = matching_courses.user_id
WHERE
    gender = 'female'
        AND birth_year BETWEEN '1991' AND '1993'
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c36b8/3

Is there a way I can accomplish this without having to select the users over again in the sub-query or without having to repeat the where clause in the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of formulating the query using a correlated subquery in the `select` clause.  This ensures that you get all users that meet the `where` conditions, even when there are no matching courses.

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
        from user_courses uc join
             user_courses uc1
             on uc.course_id = uc1.course_id and
                uc.user_id = u.id and
                uc1.user_id = 1
      ) as matching_courses_count
from users u
where u.gender = 'female' and
      birth_year BETWEEN 1991 AND 1993;
```

The correlated subquery simply counts the number of courses between the user and user 1.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer. This would be a clean approach expect attempting to access u.id within the subquery fails for me with Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'. Any ideas?

Comment: @ScotCalvin . . . That should correlated with the `from users u` clause in the outer query.  If you put up a SQL Fiddle, I can make it work.

Comment: I have updated the question to include a SQL Fiddle of the schema and my query.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be accomplished like this. The idea is that you select the user that you're interested in. Then you get the courses they take. Then you get the other rows from the course table with the same course id and finally you grab the users that take those courses.

In the where clause you then limit the result to users that have the criteria you want. And filter out the results where user 1 and 2 are the same.

```
    select *
    from users u1
    left join user_courses uc1 
    on u1.id = uc1.user_id
    left join user_courses uc2
    on uc2.course_id = uc1.course_id
    left join users u2
    on uc2.user_id = u2.id

    where u1.id = 1 and
          u2.gender = 'female' and u2.birth_year between '1991' and '1993' and
          u1.id != u2.id
```

Then you can wrap this result in another query to do the count of courses in common like this:

```
select id, count(*) from (
        select uc1.course_id, u2.id
        from users u1
        left join user_courses uc1 
        on u1.id = uc1.user_id
        left join user_courses uc2
        on uc2.course_id = uc1.course_id
        left join users u2
        on uc2.user_id = u2.id

        where u1.id = 1 and
              u2.gender = 'female' and u2.birth_year between '1991' and '1993' and
              u1.id != u2.id) as x
    group by id
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Hans, however there are several things missing; the count of matching courses, the user ID we pass in and final grouped users. Would be good to hear how you would accomplish that.